# Mandrill API to Google Sheets Script

Tags: google-apps-script

I want to call the Mandrill API in order to have tagged template data populate in my google sheet labeled test, but I can't seem to get it working (spent hours I am a beginner). Below is my code

```
function mandrill() {
var from = "https://mandrillapp.com/api/1.0/tags/list.json";
var key = "*************";
var params = {
"return" :[
  "time",
  "sent",
  "opens",
  "clicks",
   ],
   "sheet": "test"
   }}
```

I followed the official docs but I can't seem to get it working. Any help at all would be greatly appreciated.
https://mandrillapp.com/api/docs/tags.JSON.html#method=all-time-series

Comment: In your script, 3 variables are created. About this, the script works. So can I ask you about the detail information of ``I can't seem to get it working``? And also can you provide the script for replicating your issue? Of course, please remove your personal information. I think that those information will help users think of the solution.

Comment: Thanks for your reply! By not working I mean nothing is being placed into Google Sheets when I run the script, ideally, It should use the API key I entered to call my mandrill account and populate the data in a Google sheet. And that is my entire script, as I mentioned I am new at this so if I am missing something that comes before or after this script I would love to know! Thanks.

Comment: Thank you for replying. Please update your question by including the detail information. And how about using [UrlFetchApp](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/url-fetch/url-fetch-app)?

Answer (score 0):

The Apps Script reference specifies how to use the fetch() method to retrieve your request from Mandrill.

https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/url-fetch/url-fetch-app

Please use

`UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, options);`

You need to `JSON.stringify()` the JSON request for the Mandrill `/urls/list.json`  and pass it as a payload into the options of the fetch request. According to the documentation you provided, the correct JSON request is:

```
{
    "key": "example key"
}
```

Subsequently, you can proceed your response and use it to populate the sheet. Please refer to:

https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/url-fetch/http-response

Then you need to parse the answer to JavaScript object, you need to parse it before accessing the content with the method `getContentText()`. You can then access the entries of interest and populate your sheet with it:

In summary, your code to retrieve the response from Mandrill should look like this:

```
function mandrill() {

var from = "https://mandrillapp.com/api/1.0/tags/list.json";
var params = {  
             "key": "*************"
               };

var payload = JSON.stringify(params);
var options = {
    'method': 'post',
    'payload': payload,
    'contentType' : 'application/json'
    };
var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, options);
var data = JSON.parse(response).getContentText());
var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("test");
sheet.getRange("A1").setValue(data['sent'])
 }
```